# Jest testing with react-flow-renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

How can I find & test a node from `react-flow-renderer`?

For example: I would like to test the `OnElementClick` provided by `react-flow-renderer`, but i don't know how to locate the node.
The official documentation for unit testing with react-flow-renderer does not exist, unfortunately.

Is there a way to unit test methods like `OnElementClick`, `OnConnect` or `OnElementsRemove`?